# Public folder is forbidden in nginx

Tags: laravel, nginx

I successfully deploy my Laravel app to in digital ocean, but my CSS & JS file are 403 (Forbidden), inside my console it show me error of net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)

how can I give permission to my CSS &JS in my nginx on digital ocean?, any help

**nginx config**

```
// nginx configuration
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name DOMAIN_NAME_OR_IP_ADDRESS;
    root /var/www/name_of_repo/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ .php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: your public folder need read and write permission

Comment: @yadusivadas how can I achieved  that? can u show me some code

Comment: I try this, but same error, ```sudo chown -R www-data.www-data public```

Comment: go to your root of project. sudo chmod -R 777 public/*

Comment: try without this too. location ~ /.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }

Comment: @yadusivadas when I remove  ```/.(?!well-known).* { deny all; }``` worked, but it may have some impact, instead of removing how can I give permission on public directory

Comment: That should probably be `location ~ /\.(?!well-known).*` - you are missing a backslash in front to the first dot.